# A set of pairwise disjoint figure-of-T shapes in plane countable?

Tags: set-theory

We can complete a T with 2 rectangles as shown (in red dots) in the image below, going  clockwise we denote each corresponding area with $P_1, P_2$ respectively. Inside $P_1, P_2$ we can easily find points $p_1, p_2$ with rational coordinates then each T will be mapped to a tuple $(p_1, p_2)$. If we can prove that for any two Ts: $P^\prime_1 \cap P_1 \ne \emptyset \wedge P^\prime_2 \cap P_2 \ne \emptyset$ never holds true then we can prove that this mapping is 1-1 hence the set is at most countable. My intuition says that if we try to intersect let's say $P^\prime_1, P_1$ there is no way to intersect $P^\prime_2, P_2$ and vice versa. But it's doesn't seem to be much of a robust proof.
So the question is - is this a right direction? Can you give me a hint how to move forward?

[image: definition of T on a whiteboard]

Comment: I included the picture in the post (I don't think you have the rights for that yet). Note that the 2 image links in the original went to the same image, there was no "second image" as the text implied.

Comment: Do the T's need to the same size all?

Comment: Thanks for including it in the post.
T's can be of an arbitrary size. 
By the second image I meant the one with number two in the picture.